# catch Fildnot found exception e and a try method

Tags: java, exception, generics

Well I have this problem and I dont know whats wrong with the codeing,

```
    catch (FilenotFoundException e){
        system.out.println("File not found");

        }
        try
        {
            FileReader freader = new FileReader("MyFile.txt");
        }
}
```

Its asking for what the error is?? I thought it may be the e not being capitalized is that the reason?

Comment: http://www.freejavaguide.com/corejava.htm

Answer (score 2):

A **try{}** block should be followed by a **catch{}** block or **finally{}** block, `you have reversed it.`

Use like this: -

```
    try {
        FileReader freader = new FileReader("MyFile.txt");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){

        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```

**As per Java Naming Convention: -**

- Class Names start with a capital letter, and all subsequent word also start with capital letter. So, `FilenotFoundException` should be `FileNotFoundException`
- And, `system` should be -> `System`.

Answer (score 1):

A `catch{}` block follows a `try{}` block, not the other way around.

Also, `FilenotFoundException` should be `FileNotFoundException`.  I doubt it will compile with the alternate spelling.  Likewise with `system` vs. `System`, as indicated in @Rohit Jain's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be otherway. `try` followed by `catch`.

```
    try
    {
        FileReader freader = new FileReader("MyFile.txt");
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7:

```
try( FileReader freader = new FileReader("MyFile.txt"))
{
```

*use freader*

```
}// try
catch( IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

catch block should follow try

```
try {
  //code that exception might occur
 }
 catch(Exception ex) {
   //catch the exception here.
  }
```

your try block should either be followed by catch or finally.

```
try {
  //code that exception might occur
 }
 finally {
  //close your resources here
 }
```